# C# Using Classes in Project

Tags: c#, class, project

I have organised my project with separate folders for groups of classes, but now in order to get to any method I have to reference the whole path like:

```
            Classes.Users.UsersClass.Get();
            Classes.Database.ConnectionClass.Test();
            if (!Classes.Database.UsersMethods.Authenticate())
            {
                Classes.Users.UsersClass.LoginFailed();
            }
```

As you can see, this is going to get messy after a while, so is there a way I can just call the class directly?

---

/Edit

This is the fixed up version:

```
    Users.GetWindowsUser();
    Connection.Test();
    if (!UserMethods.Authenticate())
    {
        Users.LoginFailed();
    }
```

Comment: yes, look at the "using" keyword. There should be some already at the top of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply put using directives on the top of the file, *or*
if you don't want the classes to be in separated namespaces go to the class file and change the namespace to project original namesapce

```
namespace myProject.SubFolder
{
.......
}
```

will be

```
namespace myProject
{
.........
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Although the other suggestions worked, this was the best way forward for me.

Comment: @hshah Note that this, while it works, can lead to less maintainable code.  There's a (good) reason Visual Studio uses folder names for default namespaces - it really improves the discoverability of your types later when working with the project.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Sorry, what do you mean by "improves discoverability of your types"?

Comment: @hshah If your project gets very large, and you need to edit code for a class, having the namespace match the folder structure makes it very quick and easy to find the class, etc.  If you don't do that, it can get messy over time, esp. with very large projects.

Comment: @ReedCopsey how large? i mean what is (in your experience) a large project? and is it bad for compiling or for run time?
i would like to know your opinion if possible.

Comment: @Star It's not bad in terms of runtime or compile time - more developer productivity.  And "large" is very subjective - but as soon as you start dealing with multiple namespaces and multiple class hierarchies, organization in your project is very helpful.  That's why this is done that way *by default* - VS tries to promote good habits (mostly).

Comment: @ReedCopsey - I don't envision my project being more than 20 forms and 15 classes.  I only started working with C# 1 month ago so still learning best practices etc.

Comment: @hshah It's just not a good habit to pick up, IMO.  I always try to write every project using best practices - you never know if it'll end up bigger than you expect, but its also nice to build good habits up front, too.  Also, if you decide to use tools like StyleCop, you'll find they complain a LOT if you do this...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`using` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the top of your C# file:

```
using Classes.Users;
using Classes.Database;
```

This would then let you type:

```
UserClass.Get();
ConnectionClass.Test();
```

That being said, I would strongly recommend not using "Class" as a suffix on every class, and also recommend not using a namespace named "Classes".  Most things in C# are classes - there is no need to suffix every class with this in terms of naming.

For details, please refer to the [Namespace Naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [Class Naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) guidelines on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks.  Advice also taken on board and everything renamed :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the appropriate using statement to the top of your file.  E.g.  using Classes.Database;

Also, in VS 2010 if you just type the name of the class without the namespace (e.g. ConnectionClass) then hit ctrl+.  it will give you the option to automatically add the appropriate using statement.